# Build of nixos.avrgcclibc fails on NixOS

Tags: avr-gcc, nixos

I am trying to install `avr-gcc-libc` on NixOS, but run into a build error.

I try to install with the command

```
nix-env -iA nixos.avrgcclibc
```

The output this produces is very long and terminates with

```
g++ -c  -DIN_GCC_FRONTEND -g -O2 -DIN_GCC  -DCROSS_DIRECTORY_STRUCTURE  -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -W -Wall -Wno-narrowing -Wwrite-strings -Wcast-qual -Wmissing-format-attribute -Woverloaded-virtual -pedantic -Wno-long-long -Wno-variadic-macros -Wno-overlength-strings   -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -Icp -I../../gcc -I../../gcc/cp -I../../gcc/../include -I../../gcc/../libcpp/include  -I../../gcc/../libdecnumber -I../../gcc/../libdecnumber/dpd -I../libdecnumber -I../../gcc/../libbacktrace   -o cp/except.o
-MT cp/except.o -MMD -MP -MF cp/.deps/except.TPo ../../gcc/cp/except.c
In file included from ./tm.h:18:0,
                 from ../../gcc/cp/except.c:27:
../../gcc/config/elfos.h:102:21: warning: invalid suffix on literal; C++11 requires a space between literal and string macro [-Wliteral-suffix]
    fprintf ((FILE), "%s"HOST_WIDE_INT_PRINT_UNSIGNED"\n",\
                     ^
../../gcc/config/elfos.h:170:24: warning: invalid suffix on literal; C++11 requires a space between literal and string macro [-Wliteral-suffix]
       fprintf ((FILE), ","HOST_WIDE_INT_PRINT_UNSIGNED",%u\n",  \
                        ^
In file included from ../../gcc/cp/except.c:1023:0:
cfns.gperf: In function 'const char* libc_name_p(const char*, unsigned int)':
cfns.gperf:101:1: error: 'const char* libc_name_p(const char*, unsigned int)' redeclared inline with 'gnu_inline' attribute
cfns.gperf:26:14: note: 'const char* libc_name_p(const char*, unsigned int)' previously declared here
cfns.gperf: At global scope:
cfns.gperf:26:14: warning: inline function 'const char* libc_name_p(const char*, unsigned int)' used but never defined
make[2]: *** [Makefile:1064: cp/except.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/tmp/nix-build-avr-gcc-libc.drv-0/gcc-5.3.0/obj-avr/gcc'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:4094: all-gcc] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/nix-build-avr-gcc-libc.drv-0/gcc-5.3.0/obj-avr'
make: *** [Makefile:852: all] Error 2
builder for ‘/nix/store/0ypaa4x9x0lsyygciasw9m1v4jswgm49-avr-gcc-libc.drv’ failed with exit code 2
error: build of ‘/nix/store/0ypaa4x9x0lsyygciasw9m1v4jswgm49-avr-gcc-libc.drv’ failed
```

What might the problem be? What can I do to get `avr-gcc-libc` to install successfully?

Comment: You should create new [issue](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/new) with required technical details.

Comment: @wizzup thanks for the tip; I opened an issue: https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/29244